# Pass a value to another page when li element is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

In my jquery mobile app, when I click a list element, I get the id of that element. Now I want to pass that id to another page so I can make a query to the database. What would be the best way to achieve this? I tried with a form to post the id, but I don't want a form with a submit button on the page. I also tried using sessionStorage, but I am unsure how to use it properly. Presently, when I click a list element, an alert shows me the id of that selected list element.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("li").click(function() {
            var journeyID = this.id;
            sessionStorage.journeyId = journeyID;
            alert(sessionStorage.journeyId);                    
            var j = getElementById(journeyDetailsForm);
            j.innerHTML = journeyID;

            //document.forms["journeyForm"].submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: sessionStorage is very simple to use, what problems did you have? If you use a form you can submit it programatically without a button.

Comment: I could put the id into a sessionStorage, but couldn't access it on another page and use it in a php function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the url of the page

```
$("li").on("click",function(){
    var url = "example.com/page.php",
        id = this.id;
    window.location= url + "?id=" + id;


});
```